# How can I make/get TOR portable?

Tags: windows, tor-install

I downloaded TOR from the Tor website and used it, it works, UNTIL I move the folder to a different location then it completely loses connection and doesnt work with any website. I found a few websites claiming to have Tor portable but they are old versions and when I ran them they could not establish a connection to the Tor network. I need a portable version of Tor that I can move wherever or else Tor is useless to me.. Can anyone help?

Comment: Now I use  Advanced Onion Router.. so much better  :)

Answer (score 2):

Here is how to create your own portable app:
https://www.makeuseof.com/tag/create-portable-app-flash-drive/

It is not tested with Tor, it may break Tor, and it might even completely negate Tor or worse. There is no native "portable apps" version of Tor for Windows. You would be better off using Tails instead. At least that lives on a USB stick.

Comment: +1 for suggesting [Tails](https://tails.boum.org/).

Answer (score 0):

I have your in a thumb drive, I installed it directly to the thumb drive, how ever you need to be careful on which version you are installing, 32 or 64. I used it in three different computers.

Comment: this isnt  helpful. I need to move tor to whatever folder. someone pls help.

Answer (score 0):

If you were using Linux or OSX, I would try using the Homebrew package manager, with its root on your USB.  Since it's Windows (you might have made that clearer in your question), there are two approaches I'd try.  First, you might install [Cygwin](https://cygwin.com/), putting the root directory on your USB.  What Cygwin does is to create an overlay that allows linux to talk to Windows.  You are also getting access to a [package manager](https://hackernoon.com/why-windows-needs-a-package-manager-3868cffdec24), which Windows is lacking and which will allow you to install tor and then help you keep it up-to-date.  I'm not 100% clear on what Cygwin needs to do to integrate itself with Windows, and how dependent that is on the Windows version, but it might work.

There may be other package managers for Windows that might do the job.  I did a quick search and came across [Chocolatey](https://chocolatey.org/).  See if it has the tor package.  There are probably others.  You might experiment to see if any of them will work.

Really the easiest thing to do would be just to install linux to the USB - Ubuntu Mate is quite straightforward and lightweight - and then you can run tor in that OS.

Answer (score 0):

I SOLVED my problem. First off, I have Brave browser wich has Tor in incognito, but this way it doesnt save history. I came across a chrome addon "onion browser button" and downloaded "Advanced Onion router" program. now I can access tor sites right in my portable browser.